# Xml Deserialization and default values

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I've got a non standard XML that include a template (default values) and specified fields. As an example is always welcomed :

```
<MyClass>
   <ArrayOfSubClass>
      <SubClass>
         <Par1>1</Par1>
         <Par2>2</Par2>
         <Par3>3</Par3>
         <ArrayOfSpecific>
            <Specific>
               <Par1>11</Par1>
            </Specific>
         </ArrayOfSpecific>
      </SubClass>
   </ArrayOfSubClass>
</MyClass>
```

I want to deserialize this class `MyClass` into an object. As you can see, `MyClass` is an collection of classes `SubClass` which has three parameters and a collection of classes `Specific`. Classes `SubClass` and `Specific` are derived from the same mother class.

What ISpecific I would like to find the default values (ie the values found in `SubClass`) unless a field is given. What I did so far is implementing a method which by reflection checks if the property of the class `Specific` has a default value of the property type, and replace it by the property of the `SubClass` if it is the case. It works very well but I don't cover all the cases. For example, imagine I have a value of the double property `Par1` in the `SubClass`, say `Par1 = 1.234`, but I want it to be now `0`. The problem is that `0` is the default value of type double, so with my method I would retrieve the value of the property in the `SubClass`.

The best would have been to deserialize the `MyClass` object first, then put all properties of classes `Specific` with the value of the same property in `SubClass`, and then deserialize again into this existing object which would change only properties that are given in the XML file.

It is quite tricky so and I can imagine that my question is not easy to understand...

[Edit:] To try to be more understandable, here is the result I'd like once deserialized

```
<MyClass>
   <ArrayOfSubClass>
      <SubClass>
         <Par1>1</Par1>
         <Par2>2</Par2>
         <Par3>3</Par3>
         <ArrayOfSpecific>
            <Specific>
               <Par1>11</Par1>
               <Par2>2</Par2>
               <Par3>3</Par3>
            </Specific>
         </ArrayOfSpecific>
      </SubClass>
   </ArrayOfSubClass>
</MyClass>
```

It is done by reflection after deserialization, if the property of `Specific` has a default value, then take the value of the class `SubClass`. The tricky case is as follow

```
<MyClass>
   <ArrayOfSubClass>
      <SubClass>
         <Par1>1</Par1>
         <Par2>2</Par2>
         <Par3>3</Par3>
         <ArrayOfSpecific>
            <Specific>
               <Par1>0</Par1> <----- 0 is the default value of a double
            </Specific>
         </ArrayOfSpecific>
      </SubClass>
   </ArrayOfSubClass>
</MyClass>
```

Presently the result would be

```
<MyClass>
   <ArrayOfSubClass>
      <SubClass>
         <Par1>1</Par1>
         <Par2>2</Par2>
         <Par3>3</Par3>
         <ArrayOfSpecific>
            <Specific>
               <Par1>1</Par1>   <---- as 0 is the default value of a double, this property is set to the value of the SubClass
               <Par2>2</Par2>
               <Par3>3</Par3>
            </Specific>
         </ArrayOfSpecific>
      </SubClass>
   </ArrayOfSubClass>
</MyClass>
```

but I want

```
<MyClass>
   <ArrayOfSubClass>
      <SubClass>
         <Par1>1</Par1>
         <Par2>2</Par2>
         <Par3>3</Par3>
         <ArrayOfSpecific>
            <Specific>
               <Par1>0</Par1>
               <Par2>2</Par2>
               <Par3>3</Par3>
            </Specific>
         </ArrayOfSpecific>
      </SubClass>
   </ArrayOfSubClass>
</MyClass>
```

Comment: I got lost in that sentence: @"The problem is that 0 is the default value of type double, so with my method I would retrieve the value of the property in the SubClass." , what do you mean, why is this a problem? What happens if you just set this value to zero?

Comment: What language are you doing this in? The post is tagged with "c", but since you're mentioning classes and reflection, I'm guessing it's something else.

Comment: @Ramy : After deserialization, I copy the values of the `SubClass` into the `Specific` if the property has a default value. The default value of a double is 0. The problem is that when I find a property in `Specific` that has a value of 0, how can I know wether it is really 0 or it is the default value ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a workaround that's solve my issue. I do the thing in two (in fact three) steps. First I deserialize the XML into my class. Second, I put all properties of the `Specific` classes to default values that I find in the `SubClass` by reflection, expect one field (the If of the `Specific` class). And third, I reload the XML into a `DataSet`. There, I look at the `DataTable` named `Specific`, and for all the properties of my class I look if there is any column of the same name, and if the cell contains a value I put it in my class.

Ouffffff !!!!
Not really beauty, but it works.

```
     DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
     xmlDS.ReadXml(filename);
     GetSpecifiedValuesInDataSet(xmlDS);

     DataTable table = xmlDS.Tables["Specific"];

     foreach(ArrayOfSubClass array in this.Items)
     {
        foreach(SubClass sub in array)
        {
           foreach(Specific specific in sub)
           {
              Type specificType = specific.GetType();

              DataRow modelRow = null;
              foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
              {
                 if(row["Par1"].ToString().Equals(specific.Par1.ToString()))
                 {
                    modelRow = row;
                    break;
                 }
              }

              if(modelRow != null)
              {
                 foreach(PropertyInfo propSpecific in specificType.GetProperties())
                 {
                    string propertyName = propSpecific .Name;
                    foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                    {
                       if(col.ColumnName.Equals(propertyName))
                       {
                          if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelRow[propertyName].ToString()))
                          {
                             object value = Convert.ChangeType(modelRow[propertyName], propSpecific.PropertyType);
                             propSpecific.SetValue(modelProd, value, null);
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

And Voila

Answer (score 0):

Here is a collection of CodeProject links for serialization that may be of benefit:

- [Binary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254617/Serialization-101-Part-I-Binary-Serialization)
- [SOAP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255559/Serialization-101-Part-II-SOAP-Serialization)
- [XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/292726/Serialization-101-Part-III-XML-Serialization)

Although I am not certain I understand your question, could you not make your classes serializable and, in the MyClass example, code the serialization for the appropriate values?

Comment: I know that my question is not clear, but that's the best I can do :-( All the classes are serializable.

Comment: Could you explain the hierarchy of your classes?  You say SubClass and Specific both inherit the same base class.  Would it be more feasible to implement an interface instead?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reason why an interface would be preferable ? The base class is just a container of various properties. For the moment, the solution I'll try is once deserialized, put all values of the class `SubClass` into the classes `Specific`, then parse into the XML file to see whether the property exists or not in the XML, and if it exists overwrite its value with the one given in the file.

Comment: I wasn't indicating an interface as being more feasible. I'm simply trying to understand the present implementation. Perhaps if you nested these classes within MyClass, you could localize variables in MyClass to direct the serialization? I haven't gotten too far into serializing/deserializing other than a couple collection classes, but it seems to me that if you serialize the object(s) in the fashion you describe, the deserialization of the object(s) will be inaccurate representations of the initial object(s). Hope your solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but the deserialization of the objects as presented is perfectly accurate. The class generated has the exact same data structure as the XML, however, I disagree with its design but I was imposed the structure and I had to find a way to deserialize this in a proper class... anyway :-)